# failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running

Tags: docker, mariadb

Trying to install docker image using dockerfile on top of Debian 10.3 and when run `docker-compose up --build`, I'm getting this issue:

```
 > [mariadb:10.3.24 13/18] RUN set -ex;         export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)";        for key in 177F4010FE56CA3336300305F1656F24C74CD1D8; do           gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key";  done;   gpg --batch --export 177F4010FE56CA3336300305F1656F24C74CD1D8 > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mariadb.gpg;       command -v gpgconf > /dev/null && gpgconf --kill all || :;        rm -r "$GNUPGHOME";     apt-key list:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c set -ex;  export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)";  for key in $GPG_KEYS; do                gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key";  done;     gpg --batch --export $GPG_KEYS > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mariadb.gpg;    command -v gpgconf > /dev/null && gpgconf --kill all || :;        rm -r "$GNUPGHOME";     apt-key list]: exit code: 2
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:10.3

...

ENV MARIADB_MAJOR 10.3
ENV MARIADB_VERSION 1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1

RUN set -ex; \
    { \
        echo "mariadb-server-$MARIADB_MAJOR" mysql-server/root_password password "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"; \
        echo "mariadb-server-$MARIADB_MAJOR" mysql-server/root_password_again password "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"; \
    } | debconf-set-selections; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y \
        "mariadb-server=$MARIADB_VERSION" \
        # mariadb-backup is installed at the same time so that `mysql-common` is only installed once from just mariadb repos
        mariadb-backup \
        socat \
    ; \
```

Anything related to specific package or other problem?